Why the left matrix of single value decomposition obtained by scipy.linalg.svd() and eigenvectors obtained from scipy.linalg.eig() are different?
I tried to get eigen vectors by single value decomposition using scipy.linalg.svd() which gives me three outputs the left matrix U, diagonal matrix S, right matrix Vh. Where U is supposed to be eigenvectors for symmetric positive definite matrix.
But eigenvectors obtained from scipy.linalg.eig() are different from U or the left matrix. Different in a sense that they have same absolute values but different signs for some of the values.
import scipy
import numpy as np
mat = np.array([[3,2],[2,3]])
U, S, Vh = scipy.linalg.svd(mat)
eigenvalues, eigenvectors = scipy.linalg.eig(mat)

print(U)
>>> [[-0.70710678 -0.70710678]
    [-0.70710678  0.70710678]]
print(eigenvectors)
>>> [[ 0.70710678 -0.70710678]
    [ 0.70710678  0.70710678]]

Maybe I am missing some mathematical point. It would be very helpful if someone explain it to me why this happens.

If you negate an eigenvector, it is still an eigenvector (for the same eigenvalue).

Eigenvectors are not unique.
